# Restore rusted chrome forks?

Tags: fork, paint, restoration, chrome

I'm restoring an old bike. I have removed two layers of paint on the forks to reveal the original chrome on the forks. Unfortuantly they have rusted, and it looks like it has gone through the chrome layers.

Is there anything I can do to restore the chrome finish (I want to do it myself)? Or is the only option to just paint the forks?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Go to an auto parts store and buy some "rust converting primer".  Use that as an undercoat for paint.  *Do not grind off the rust first!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your two options are (if you want to do this properly)

1. Paint will not properly adhere to the chrome, so, sand or grind of the chrome, rust etc, fill pits and irregularities, sand to proper condition for painting, properly prime, paint and clearcoat. Removing chrome probably requires use of special filtration masks.
2. The same, except have the fork re-chromed instead of painting. Classic and vintage car part restoration services is probably your best bet to do that.

Comment: It's opinion based but I think it's a shame to paint over a chromed fork or any other part, especially on a vintage machine. But for the sake of originality I would have the fork re-chromed if only possible.